# Adding a cumulative sum column in a data.table with a minimum threshold

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data.table in R with a column called "score" containing both positive and negative real numbers. I want to add a new column called "sum" which represents the cumulative sum of the "score" column. However, I need the cumulative sum to have a minimum threshold. If the sum at any point falls below the minimum threshold, it should be set to the minimum value, and the next step of the cumulative sum should start from that minimum value.

I have tried using the cumsum() function to calculate the cumulative sum, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the minimum threshold logic. Here's my code so far:

```
dt <- data.table(score = c(10, -13, 8, -12, 6))

dt[, sum := cumsum(score)]

# its wrong
print(dt)

   score sum
1:    10  10
2:   -13  -3
3:     8   5
4:   -12  -7
5:     6  -1
```

I also tried

```
min_value <- -3
dt[, sum := {
  temp_sum <- cumsum(score)
  temp_sum[temp_sum < min_value] <- min_value
  temp_sum
}]

# its also wrong
print(dt)
   score sum
1:    10  10
2:   -13  -3
3:     8   5
4:   -12  -3
5:     6  -1 # expected sum is 3 here
```

I also have tried this from [Cumulative sum with a threshold window in R data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474370/cumulative-sum-with-a-threshold-window-in-r-data-table) and [dplyr / R cumulative sum with reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076769/dplyr-r-cumulative-sum-with-reset?rq=2)

```
sum_score <- function(thresh) {
  function(x) {
    purrr::accumulate(x, ~dplyr::if_else(.x<=thresh, .y, .x+.y))
  }  
}

dt[, sum := sum_score(-3)(score)]

print(dt)
   score sum
1:    10  10
2:   -13  -3
3:     8   8
4:   -12  -4
5:     6   6
```

Expected output:

```
   score sum
1:    10  10
2:   -13  -3
3:     8   5
4:   -12  -3
5:     6  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you preferably want a `data.table` solution but here is a simple `dplyr` method, which first generated the `cumsum` then alters its values accordingly:

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.frame(score = c(10, -13, 8, -12, 6))

thresh = -3

dt %>% mutate(sum = cumsum(score)) %>% 
  mutate(sum = case_when(
    lag(sum) < thresh ~ score + thresh,
    sum < thresh ~ thresh,
    is.na(sum) ~ score,
    .default = sum)
    )
```

Output:

```
  score   sum
1    10    10
2   -13    -3
3     8     5
4   -12    -3
5     6     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
dt <- data.table::data.table(score = c(10, -13, 8, -12, 6, -20, 40))

dt |> 
  mutate(
    ID = row_number(),
    raw_score = score,
    indicator = (ifelse(cumsum(score) < -3, row_number(), NA))) |> 
  fill(indicator) |> 
  group_split(indicator) |> 
  map_dfr(~.x |> 
        mutate(score = ifelse(
          !is.na(indicator) & row_number() == 1, -3, score
        ))) |> 
  arrange(ID) |> 
  group_by(indicator) |> 
  mutate(sum = cumsum(score)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(raw_score, sum)
```

**Output**:

```
  raw_score   sum
      <dbl> <dbl>
1        10    10
2       -13    -3
3         8     5
4       -12    -3
5         6     3
6       -20    -3
7        40    37
```